# how to use enum with DescriptionAttribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, asp.net-mvc-5.2, enumdropdownlistfor

I am new to asp.net MVC. I am trying to use dropdown control on my view page, which populates from enum. I also want to add custom descriptions to dropdown values. I searched so many examples, but no one posted how to populated description on view page. Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
public enum SearchBy
    {
        [Description("SID/PID")]
        SID = 1,
        [Description("Name")]
        Name,
        [Description("Birth Date")]
        DOB,
        [Description("Cause#")]
        Cause
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.searchBy, "Search By", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.TextBox("searchByVal", null, htmlAttributes: new { @placeholder = "SID / PID ", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "First Name", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Last Name", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Birth Date", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CauseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CauseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Cause#", @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not populating the with description fields as mentioned in my SearchBy enum. see the image here. 
http://postimg.org/image/phdxgocj7/
Please help me, where I am making mistake. Thank you

**UPDATE:**
I got solution for this from Nico. And I researched little bit on this. I am updating this post with solution because it may useful to others, who are new to MVC
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-1-overview-and-enums

Thank you all. Enjoy coding..

Comment: There is no `EnumDropDownListFor()` method in MVC-4. Do you mean MVC-5 or is this a custom helper?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the tag. Yes, I am using MVC-5

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Html helper `EnumDropDownListFor` or `EnumDropDownList` does not take into consideration the `Description` attribute decorations on the `enum` members.  However by reviewing the source code:

Enum Dropdown List Helper:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs

Enum Helper Classes: 
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/EnumHelper.cs

The enum helper classes above are used to convert an `Enum` to a `List<SelectListItem>`. From the code below:

```
// Return non-empty name specified in a [Display] attribute for the given field, if any; field's name otherwise
private static string GetDisplayName(FieldInfo field)
{
    DisplayAttribute display = field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(inherit: false);
    if (display != null)
    {
        string name = display.GetName();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    return field.Name;
}
```

You can see that in the method `GetDisplayName` it checks for the existence of the `DisplayAttribute` on the `enum` member. If the display attribute exists then the name is set to the result of `DisplayAttribute.GetName()` method.

Putting this together we can modify the `enum` to use the `DisplayAttribute` instead of the `DescriptionAttribute` and setting the `Name` property to the value you wish to display.

```
public enum SearchBy
{
    [Display(Name = "SID/PID")]
    SID = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    Name,
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    DOB,
    [Display(Name = "Cause#")]
    Cause
}
```

This gives you the result you wish.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Nico. This helps, but in the view page, what I should replace EnumDropDownListFor  with?

Comment: After a little bit research, I understand that, I have to write Display template for rendering Enum properly to view as dropdown, correct? correct me, if I am wrong. I found an article on this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776908/Dealing-with-Enum-in-MVC

Answer (score 6):

I created a helper class that tries different types of attributes.  I needed it because I was using bootstrap with https://github.com/civicsource/enums and https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
    {
        static EnumHelper()
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);
            if (!enumType.IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentException("Type '" + enumType.Name + "' is not an enum"); }
        }

        public static string GetEnumDescription(T value)
        {
            var fi = typeof(T).GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[]) fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList()
        {
            var groupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, SelectListGroup>();

            var enumType = typeof(T);
            var fields = from field in enumType.GetFields()
                         where field.IsLiteral
                         select field;

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var display = field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false);
                var description = field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(false);
                var group = field.GetCustomAttribute<CategoryAttribute>(false);

                var text = display?.GetName() ?? display?.GetShortName() ?? display?.GetDescription() ?? display?.GetPrompt() ?? description?.Description ?? field.Name;
                var value = field.Name;
                var groupName = display?.GetGroupName() ?? group?.Category ?? string.Empty;
                if (!groupDictionary.ContainsKey(groupName)) { groupDictionary.Add(groupName, new SelectListGroup { Name = groupName }); }

                yield return new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = text,
                    Value = value,
                    Group = groupDictionary[groupName],
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

And you call it like:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Address.State, EnumHelper<StateProvince>.GetSelectList(), new { @class = "selectpicker show-menu-arrow", data_live_search = "true" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

---

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create a helper class if you're using `.Net Framework 4.0` or newer.

You can just use the `Display` attribute in conjunction with `EnumDropDownListFor`

```
public enum SearchBy
{
    [Display(Name = "SID/PID")]
    SID = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    Name,
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    DOB,
    [Display(Name = "Cause#")]
    Cause
}
```

In your View:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SearchBy, "Search By", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3):

Given :

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("This is the description if my member A")]
    A,
    [Description("This is the description if my member B")]
    B
}
```

I personally use this extension method to get a description from my enum:

```
 public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                return attributes[0].Description;
            }
            else
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

To use it:

```
MyEnum.A.GetDescription();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Nico helped me in resolving the issue.